# Error deploying vuejs app to ubuntu server with gitlab runner

Tags: vue.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to deploy an app from a GitLab repo to a server running ubuntu 20.04.
GitLab runner is registered and running, all SSH key's are added; I made .gitlab-ci.yml but get an error "Permission denied (Public key)". I fixed that and now I am getting `dist/*: No such file or directory`

My .gitlab-ci.yml is here:

```yaml
stages:
   - build
   - deploy

# build stage
build_app:
   image: node:alpine
   stage: build
   only:
      - master
   script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build
   cache:
     paths:
       - node_modules/ 
   artifacts:
      paths:
         # build folder
         - dist/
      expire_in: 1 hour

# production stage
production:
   stage: deploy
   before_script:
      - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
   script:
      - scp -r dist/* root@server_ip:/var/www/html/my_app
```

My task is to make .gitlab-cd.yml that will build the app in docker and send that build to the production server. I read all documentation but now I am totally confused and have no idea what am I doing at all.

Can someone help and guide me?

Comment: You can try to use full path to artifacts directory: `scp -r ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/dist/* ...`. If it does not help, then you can add `ls` in your script, and check which files in your build directory are presented.

Comment: One noob question, where can i find my CI_PROJECT_DIR and how can i make pipeline start everytime on new merge

Comment: `CI_PROJECT_DIR` is environment variable (gitlab defines it https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html ), you can add `echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR` to see what is it.

Comment: for start everytime on new merge you can add `only: - merge_requests` for job ( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html#use-only-or-except-to-run-pipelines-for-merge-requests )

Answer (score 0):

#### why scp fails

Check is your `dist` directory exists and has smth inside: `- ls dist` (you will see output of the command in "job console" in gitlab)

I think that directory is empty then need check `build_app` job

#### how to run job only on merge requests?

add `only: - merge_requests`  for job [read more](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html#use-only-or-except-to-run-pipelines-for-merge-requests)

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: ./deploy
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

#### misc

I suggest use `rsync` instead of `scp` it's employs a special delta transfer algorithm and a few optimizations to make the operation faster.

Comment: I changed to rsync and i am getting permission denied error even public and private ssh keys are added

Comment: @user38974 first of all check what happen with your `dist` directory